# How can I add an attribute to an item in SimpleDB only if the item already exists?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I'd like to add an attribute only if the Item I'm adding it to doesn't already exist.

From what I can tell, the UpdateCondition construct only allows you to update based on whether specific attributes of an item exist with specified values.

Answer (score -2):

[Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/ConditionalPut.html) is the help link for performing a Conditional Put.

[Help](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/ConditionalPut.html#ExistenceCheck) link for using conditional puts to only put an attribute if it does not exist.

**Edited:**

You can not check the existence of an item without running Amazon SimpleDB Query. You can query for an item and if amazon simpledb does not return that item in request, means that item does not exist. 
Check the sample code -

```
try {
            BasicAWSCredentials basicAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("<accessKey>", "<secretkey>");
            AmazonSimpleDBClient amazonSimpleDBClient = new AmazonSimpleDBClient(basicAWSCredentials);
            amazonSimpleDBClient.setEndpoint("sdb.amazonaws.com");
            SelectRequest selectRequest = new SelectRequest("select * from `<domainName>` where itemName()='<itemName>'");
            SelectResult selectResult = amazonSimpleDBClient.select(selectRequest);
            List<Item> itemList = selectResult.getItems();
            if (itemList.size() == 0) {
                System.out.println("Specified item does not exist.");
                List<ReplaceableAttribute> list = new ArrayList<ReplaceableAttribute>();
                ReplaceableAttribute replaceableAttribute = new ReplaceableAttribute("<attribute>", "<value>", Boolean.TRUE);
                list.add(replaceableAttribute);
                PutAttributesRequest attributesRequest = new PutAttributesRequest("<domainName>", "<itemName>", list);
                amazonSimpleDBClient.putAttributes(attributesRequest);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Specified item exist. Do Nothing.");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
```

Comment: ConditionalPut only works based on whether an attribute already exists with a specified value.

Comment: What if the item is removed by another process after we've done the select statement?

Comment: @ThomShutt Amazon SimpleDB does not return or throw any exception when item does not exist, when we are putting an attribute into the domain. So every time, you need to query before you about to put an attribute in your case.

Comment: I meant that there's a race condition in your code if the item is removed by another process after the select statement is done.

Comment: @ThomShutt That is the different issue from the above question that you asked. As I answered to your original question - `you can check existence of item by running SELECT query and if Amazon SimpleDB does not return that item then you can request to put attribute.` FYI - You can `Synchronized` the object of `AmazonSimpleDBClient` to avoid race around condition.